# How to run multiple login sessions on the same target server in the same browser?

Tags: firefox, browser

As an example: Let's say someone wanted to run up 5 instances of Gmail in Firefox. Each instance being ran as a different Gmail account.

IF you are logged into Gmail and you open another Firefox tab or window and visit Gmail you will still be logged in with the same session. How does one log into to multiple instances of the same service in the same browser under different accounts/sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only looking to have multiple gmail sessions, google supports multiple connections to google accounts you can have multiple google accounts connected at the same time, I don't think firefox or any browser supports multiple login like if its tabs were all independants.

Edit: I found [this other superuser request](https://superuser.com/questions/690/how-can-i-get-a-new-browser-session-when-opening-a-new-tab-or-window-on-firefox) which I guess is similar to what you want to achieve, might be helpfull if still up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was able to find on it Multifox and it will open new windows in which it does exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I also learned something new from your request ^^

Comment: @Stakhanov For chrome they mention *Incognito mode*. Isn't his Firefox counterpart *Private mode* the same? I can't test it but I thought with private mode you are also able to have multiple sessions

Comment: yeah I guess incognito mode  or private mode can achieve this, but its not really the primary intend of that mode and it has a lot of cons that some people wouldn't want for everyday browsing...