# Chrome - Open separate browser windows, each in incognito mode, that do not share data between

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to be logged into 3 different gmail accounts at once.

I thought that command/switch combination would accomplish this by opening new browser windows with separate incognito mode:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -incognito --new-window https://mail.google.com
```

Clicking on the shortcut will launch a new window, and it will be incognito, and it will be directed to gmail. I then log in, and then rerun the shortcut and log in with my next account

But, the 2nd window that launches is logged in as my 1st user (why is chrome sharing cookies accross incognito windows - scary!) If I change the log in inside session 2, I then lose the 1st session's log in!

I need the igcognito windows to each be in their **own** session. How can I acheive this?

Any ideas?

Thanks

(*Note: I actually want to acheive this with an intranet site - not gmail, but I am using gmail to illustrate my point*)

Comment: Oddly, I'm looking for how to do this too- AND I know I found another commandline swith that made it work... but I can't find it now for the life of me (maybe it was for IE or something...)

Comment: For my answer to this question, please see https://superuser.com/a/1195333/203848.

Comment: It is not duplicate. There is big difference between: 1) "do not share data between different incognito windows" (the question) 2) "new browser session while opening new tab" (other question) . Thank you @Carl

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All incognito windows share a common set of cookies - this is [by](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=15632) [design](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24690).

Your best option is to use an extension such as [MultiLogin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multilogin/nccllfnllopfpcbjdgjdlfmomnfgnnbk).

Comment: A strange design indeed. So "incognito" doesn't isolate a tab from all other tabs, just from tabs running in regular mode.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: Yes, just think of it as two independent sessions - one for all your normal windows/tabs and one for all your incognito windows/tabs. Presumably they didn't allow all incognito windows to be truly independent because of the added complexity.

Comment: re: MultiLogin: this was posted on the "by design" link page Sun, Dec 22, 2019, 7:25 PM MST: "FYI MUltiLogin on the store is spyware and you're fools for using it."

Comment: Do you guys know if this is confirmed to be spyware? As per comment on chromium.org https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24690#c133

Answer (score 10):

You can start several instances of Chrome [with different profiles](https://superuser.com/questions/377186/how-do-i-start-chrome-using-a-specified-user-profile), each having an isolated set of cookies.

Also, google supports [being logged into several accounts at once](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977?hl=en) to some extent, but this does not really apply to your case.